# PDO driver stopped working with error of start using ODBC instead? without version?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, driver, sqlsrv

Recently our SQL Server database has been upgraded and my PDO driver stoped working.
Currently im getting error:

> SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for
> SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to
> download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64:
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712

When i connect to the db via MSSMC I see:

```
Operation System: Microsoft Windows NT 6.3 (14393)
Platform: NT x64
Version: 13.0.5292.0
```

and my PHP server runs on:

```
Linux x64
PHP Version 7.2.5
Thread Safely: disabled
```

Currently PDO Driver is loaded for SQLSRV in version 5.8.0

All was working to recently just fine, from noe on just stopped with that error :(

Can I kindly ask you to help me choose the correct driver file?
from the link in the error its very confusing to choose which .so file it realy should be used.

Thank you

Comment: For PHP Driver for SQL Server v5.8, running on a 64-bit platform: ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server (x64) is the first option.

Comment: but I dont have SQL Server v5.8, but as post says (sorry, corrected now) its version 13

Comment: It`s PHP Driver for SQL Server 5.8 (the latest version) and that version needs ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server (x64).